# Django Form not updating data in the model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-forms

this is my first Django project and I am stuck. If not a solution, but just a hint on what I am doing wrong will be truly appreciated.

I have a model with one attribute set as Null by default and I want to use a Form to update that attribute with the ID taken from another model.
These are the 2 models:

models.py

```
class Squad(models.Model):
    squad_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.squad_name

class AvailablePlayer(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    squad = models.ForeignKey(Squad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name
```

This is the form:

forms.py

```
class AddSquadToPlayerForm(forms.Form):
    # squad the player will be added to
    squad_to_player = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddSquadToPlayerForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['squad_to_player'].queryset = AvailablePlayer.objects.all()
```

This is the view file, where I think something is missing/wrong:

views.py

```
def add_player_to_squad(request, squad_id):
    # player = AvailablePlayer.objects.get(id=squad_id)
    squad = Squad.objects.get(id=squad_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPlayerToSquadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.squad = form.cleaned_data['id']
            form.save()
            return redirect('fanta_soccer_app:squad', squad_id=squad_id)
    else:
        form = AddPlayerToSquadForm(queryset=AvailablePlayer.objects.all())
    context = {"squad": squad, "form": form}
    return render(request, 'fanta_soccer_app/add_player.html', context)
```

And finally, this is html file

add_player.html

```
<body>
<p>Add a new player to the Squad:</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'fanta_soccer_app:squad' squad.id %}">{{ squad }}</a></p>
<form action="{% url 'fanta_soccer_app:add_player' squad.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" >Add player</button>
</form>
</body>
```

The rendered html shows correctly a form with a drop down menu correctly populated with the objects in the database from the "AvailablePlayer" model, however when selecting one and clicking on "Add", nothing happens, and selected player is not added to the DB.

Thank you in advance for your time.

EDIT: the code in views.py has been modified according to a comment

ADDITIONAL INFO: to confirm the db is working, if I manually add the squad_id to one of the AvailablePlayer(s) in the DB, it will be correctly listed in the squad details view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by myself, and sharing here the solution:

1. I changed the form field from ModelMultipleChoiceField to ModelChoiceField. ModelMultipleChoiceField is for ManyToMany relationships model fields, while mine is a ForeignKey. I have also removed the **init** method:

```
squad_to_player = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AvailablePlayer.objects.all())
```

2. The view was pretty messed up,  as I was aware of, but after fixing the above, I started to have error logs, so I could eventually come up with the following solution:

view.py

```
def add_player_to_squad(request, squad_id):
    squad = Squad.objects.get(id=squad_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPlayerToSquadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            player_to_sign = form.cleaned_data['squad_to_player']
            player_to_sign.squad = squad
            player_to_sign.save()
            return redirect('fanta_soccer_app:squad', squad_id=squad_id)
    else:
        form = AddPlayerToSquadForm()
    context = {"squad": squad, "form": form}
    return render(request, 'fanta_soccer_app/add_player.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) I think where you are going wrong is that you are trying to update an existing value, which requires you to pass an instance keyword argument to `form.save()`.

So I think you need to do something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    a = Squad.objects.get(id=squad_id)
    form = AddSquadToPlayerForm(request.POST, instance=a)
    form.squad = form.cleaned_data['id']
    form.save()
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up on the instance, that was something I had to fix too. However it still does not work as expected.

Comment: Have you checked that your code is reaching the block after form.is_valid?

Comment: I check and it is actually not valid, and I am trying to figure it out why. If I add print(request.POST) before form.is_valid(), I can see that the form correctly send the player_to _squad value (so the item selected from the dropdown list), but the "submit" attribute of <button> is empty - 
<button name="submit" type="submit" >Add player</button>

Comment: Oh so that's the problem. What happens if you print out form.errors.as_data()?

Comment: it is empty: {}

Comment: That's strange - there should be errors if it isn't validating. Do you get anything from form.errors? You're printing this after submitting the form? Also, what happens if you swap the button tag for <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237070/discussion-between-flavior-and-osint-alex).